How can I assign a value to a list of out simple port?
I have a list of out simple port :
epready : list of out simple_port of bit is instance;
I want to assign a value to it, e.g :
p_smp.epready$ = 0;

but I got an error :

Error: Trying to extract bits from list of out simple_port of bi

How to assign a value to that port without driving each bit separately?
no documented solution for that

Try to assign an element of the list not the complete list at once
